# How to listen for changes in local storage in the same tab in React?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, use-effect

In component X I am updating local storage, I want to listen for these changes in component Y. I tried this code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("storage", () => console.log("change"));
  }, []);
```

But it doesn't listen for changes in the same tab (when changes are made in different tab - it works).

What would be the correct approach for this problem? Is listening for local storage changes a good way or should I come up with state management through for example useContext?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? If you just want to share data between components, localStorage is not the way to do it. You should look into [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), and yes, potentially React Context as well.

Comment: I'm setting "favourite items" in different component- they are saved in local storage. When I click a button in component X - then the item in component X is added to "favourite". In component Y I display the "favourite items" and here I want to listen for changes to update the "favourite" list.

Answer (score 1):

In component X:

```
const fakeWindow = window.open('', '');
fakeWindow.localStorage.setItem('date', Date.now().toString());
fakeWindow.close();
```

In component Y:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', myFunction);
```